# highlight current page menu li

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Is there a way for me to highlight a menu li depending on the page id? I can't seem to figure out a way to do it.

http://www.dawaf.co.uk/cthm/work/

```
<div id="header">
    <h1>
        <a href="http://www.dawaf.co.uk/cthm/work">
            <img src="http://www.dawaf.co.uk/cthm/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/logo2.png" alt="CTHM Logo" id="logo" width="140" height="44" />    
        </a>
        <div id="contact-details">
            26 Queen Anne Road, London, E9 7AH<br />
            t + 44 7912325101<br />
            <a href="mailto:hello@cthm.co.uk">hello@cthm.co.uk</a>
        </div>
    </h1>
    <div id="nav">
        <span id="nav-li">
            <a href="http://www.dawaf.co.uk/cthm/work/" class="work-current">Work</a>
            <a href="http://www.dawaf.co.uk/cthm/studio/" class="studio-current">Studio</a>
            <a href="http://cthmplus.tumblr.com/" target="_blank">CTHM&#43;</a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/hello_cthm" target="_blank">
                <img src="http://www.dawaf.co.uk/cthm/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" width="13" height="13">
            </a>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="content">
```

Comment: You'll first need to specify an "activepage" class to the anchor that is displayed . You can then style like `.activepage {color:green;}` for example.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding an active class to the navigation item. Something like this:

```
<a href="http://www.dawaf.co.uk/cthm/work/" class="active">Work</a>
```

And then the CSS:

```
#nav a.active {
  /* your active style here */
}
```

Comment: How do I then differentiate between the 'Work' and 'Studio' page being active? Do I need to do it using a page ID?

Comment: Ideally, you want to add the active class on the server side, when the page is being built. If that's not an option, you can do it with jQuery like this: `$("#nav").find("a[href='" +window.location.href+ "']").addClass("active");`

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. One is that mentioned by Zak, whereby you would need to use jQuery for your website to mark only one item at a time as "active". The other option is the CSS :active selector, which will auto apply CSS to the link which is in use (at the present time). For example:

```
#nav li a:active {
  /* Insert styling here, such as, background-color: #01B */
}
```

Let me know if this helps!